# Format function output as data frame

Tags: r, dataframe, tapply

I use the following to sum several measures of TABR per Julian date in 5 separate years:

```
TABR_YearDay<-with(wsmr, tapply(TABR, list(Julian, Year),sum))
```

Which produces output like:

```
     2015 2016 2017 2018 2019
33    NA   NA   NA    2   NA
....

80    NA    1   NA   21   NA

81    NA   47   NA   25   NA

82    NA   12    1    9   NA
```

But I want to convert these results into a dataframe with 6 columns Julian + 2015-2019.

I tried:

```
TABR_Day<-as.data.frame(TABR_YearDay)
```

But that seems to not produce a fully realized df: there is no column for Julian and if I want to call an individual variable, I have to use quotes around it like:

```
hist(TABR_Day$"2017")
```

Can you help me transition the function output to a dataframe with 6 viable columns?

Answer (score 0):

The column is present in the rownames of the result. Column names usually don't start with a number, we can prepend the column name with the word `'Year'` to make it `'Year_2015'` etc and construct the final dataframe.

```
TABR_YearDay<-with(wsmr, tapply(TABR, list(Julian, Year),sum))
colnames(TABR_YearDay) <- paste0('Year_', colnames(TABR_YearDay))
TABR_Day <- data.frame(Julian = rownames(TABR_YearDay), TABR_YearDay)
```